# Divide and conquer recursive solution for making change

Tags: python, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to implement a divide and conquer program that when given a coin set c = {c0, c1,...,cn} and an amount A, it finds how many different ways A can be paid, as well as how many times the function was recursed through.

My thought is to do something like this:

```
callsMade = 0
coins = [1,5,10,25]

def makeChange(A, c):
    global callsMade
    callsMade += 1
    if(A == 0):
        return 1
    if(A < 0):
        return 0
    combos = 0
    for i in range(len(coins)):
        combos += makeChange(A - coins[i], i)
    return combos
```

Where A is the amount being passed in and c = len(coins)-1.
Though, this snippet of code doesn't behave as I expect it to. My thought process is to loop through the array of coins, subtracting the current amount by the coin in that position of the array and recursively call the makeChange function with the lower amount and next coin in the array, then increment the global callsMade by 1 each time.

Using the coinset = [1,5,10,25] and amount A = 200, the amount of combinations should be 1463 with around 1500 calls made.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. In the middle you say this doesn't work as expected. What happens? What do you want help with? (Don't you also need to check `coins[I]` is less than A?

Comment: What is the point of passing in ``c``? It is not used.

Comment: Currently it gives me the wrong amount of combinations and I can't even call it with a value over 50 because the program slows to a crawl. So firstly, I'd like help understanding if my thought process on this divide and conquer problem is correct, and then hopefully find my mistake in that snippet.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi correct. my thought was to use it to iterate through the coins list, and increment it before making another recursive call. I'm confused as to how I bring this all together to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence relation looks something like this (I removed the calls counter for brevity):

```
def makeChange(A, coins, k=0):
    if A == 0: return 1
    if A <  0: return 0
    return sum(makeChange(A - coins[i], coins, i) for i in range(k, len(coins)))
```

I.e., you do not consider coins that are smaller than those you have already taken, otherwise you will get combination like `[1, 1, 5]` and `[1, 5, 1]` and so on. With this, I get 1463 combinations for `makeChange(200, (1,5,10,25))` with a total of 111491 calls -- a bit more than what you expected.

Note that this function will calculate many combinations more than once. E.g., you can reach `A=194` by `[1,5]` or by `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`, and so on, but the result for `makeChange(194, coins, k=1)` is the same for both ways. You can use `functools.lru_cache` to automatically memoize those values. This way, you get the same result after just 801 calls.

```
@functools.lru_cache(None)
def makeChange(A, coins, k=0):
    # same as above
```

(For memoization, you have to include the `coins` as a parameter (as a `tuple`, not a `list`, in order to be hashable), otherwise it would reuse the result for a different set of coins.)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is right, but you need to consider some issues with the recursion and what you want to count as a correct answer.

If you start simply, you can ask how many combinations of `[1,5,10,25]` should equal `6`:

Should it be 3:
`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [5, 1], [1, 5]`?
or 2:
`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 5]`?

Two makes the most sense to me. To do this you need to pass a subset of your coins array back to the recursion so when you are in the for loop looking at 5 you don't consider `[5, 1]` again — presumable you've already counted `[1, 5]` at this point. Instead of passing the unused `c` parameter, pass in a `coins` list. Then manage that list in the loop. Here I've added an extra parameter `cur` to collect the combinations just to help check the work. You don't need that if you just want the count.

```
def makeChange(A, coins, cur = None):
    ''' This will also collect the combinations to check the work'''
    if cur is None:
        cur = []
    global callsMade
    callsMade += 1
    if(A == 0):
        print(cur)
        return 1
    if(A < 0):
        return 0
    combos = 0
    for i, coin in enumerate(coins):
        if coin > A: # don't bother if coin is too big
            continue
        # pass a subset of the list into recursion
        combos += makeChange(A - coin, coins[i:], cur + [coin])
    return combos

coinset = [1,5,10,25]
A = 10
makeChange(A, coinset)
```

Result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
[5, 5]
[10]
Out[456]:
4
```

Setting `A` to `200` shows `1463` combinations.

Comment: Thanks for this description, passing the subset makes sense and does cut the normal recursive calls in about half. But this implementation still does 78,903 recursive calls, which makes me think there's an even more efficient way besides complete memoization. The calls made should be around 1570.

Comment: @pweave there are a lot more combinations than 1570. To get fewer calls you can memoize the function. You can actually bring down the number of calls to 764 using [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) or writing your own.